# Excel and VLOOKUP

Tags: excel, vlookup

I am working a project where I need to find certain words and replace them with a number in another column. However I cant find a way to make it work for the large amount of information

For Example: A Is the column where i am taking the old information. B is where I need to take the old information and replace it while the numerically code given in column C

`A                  B                 C`

`Single             01               Single = 01`

`Single             01              Married = 02`

`Single             01              Unknown = 98`

`Married            02              Divorced = 99`

`unknown            98              Separated = 05`

`Divorced           99`

`Separated          98`

I'm not sure how to get it to work . So any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: So...what happened when you used VLOOKUP? What was the output? What were you expecting? Is your code extract what happened after you tried, or is it the final structure you are seeking? Your definition of your algorithm needs clarification, and some effort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rob, you look up range has to be a two-column layout, not a one-column as you have it.
Assuming your data starts at row 1, your current lookup range is C1:C5. I would do the following:

```
1) Assign cell C1 to value of "Single", C2 = "Married", C3 = "Unknown", C4 = "Divorced", C5 = "Separated".
2) D1 should be "01", D2 = "02", D3 = "98", D4 = "99", D5 = "05"
3) B1 = =VLOOKUP($A1,$C$1:$D$5,2,)
4) Copy this formula down so B7 =VLOOKUP($A7,$C$1:$D$5,2,)
5) If you like to handle any errors and assign unknown values to "98", you can change cell B1 to have this formula instead: =IFERROR(VLOOKUP($A1,$C$1:$D$5,2,),"98")
```

Comment: Thanks Rob, I'm glad that this solution worked for you. Could you please accept and rate/vote for my answer?